# Convert dictionary key tuple to string

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary

```
dicts = {('name1','name2','name3'): Engineer}
```

I want to make the key (that is tuple) as one string so my output could look like this:

```
dicts = {'name1,name2,name3': Engineer}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.join`.

```
dicts = {('name1','name2','name3'): 'Engineer'}

new_dct = {}
for k,v in dicts.items():
    new_dct[','.join(k)] = v
    
print(new_dct)
```

---

```
{'name1,name2,name3': 'Engineer'}
```

**Update base comment** If you want to use on `int/float` you can use `map(str, tuple)`.

```
>>> dicts = {(264.0,264.0,264.0): '264'} 
>>> {','.join(map(str, k)): v for k,v in dicts.items()}
{'264.0,264.0,264.0': '264'}
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I tried to replace current dictionary with a new one
dicts = {('name1','name2','name3'): '264'}

I got this error : TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @J1701, welcome, I check this dict that you say : `dicts = {('name1','name2','name3'): '264'}` and don't get any error.

Answer (score 5):

Use `join()` to convert the tuple to a delimited string.

```
dicts = {",".join(key): value for key, value in dicts.items()}
```