# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Tags: python

As I already asked on ([Convert dictionary key tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092832/convert-dictionary-key-tuple-to-string/73092844#73092844)), but this time I have a `dict={("name1","name2","name3"):256}`

I want my dict to be `dict={"name1,name2,name3":256}` but when I try this I get an error:

```
    new_dct = {}
    for k,v in dicts.items():
        new_dct[','.join(k)] = v
**TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found**
```

(i removed all nanS)
Any idea?

Comment: it can't raise that error with that input

Comment: @Matiiss That's not correct. With `dicts={(1.0, "name1"):256}` it would raise that exception (plus or minus the item number), and OP has not shown how `dicts` gets assigned.

Comment: @constantstranger yes, it is correct, they say that they have a `dict = {("name1", "name2", "name3"): 256}` which is their provided sample input apparently and with it, that error gets raised, that's false, with that input and that code, that error can't be raised, you basically said the same thing in your answer (questionable why it's even an answer, but sure)

Comment: My point is that the code uses `dicts` (not `dict`), and we're not shown what's in `dicts`.

Comment: @Matiss to put a finer point on the matter: whatever input OP is using in `dict`, because the code references the variable `dicts` whose value we are not shown, the exception shown in OP's question is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
d = {("name1", "name2", "name3"): 256}
new_d = {','.join(map(str, k)): v for k, v in d.items()}
print(new_d) # {'name1,name2,name3': 256}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with `dict` renamed as `d` and used in the loop in place of `dicts` (the value of which is unclear), and it seems to work fine:

```py
d={("name1","name2","name3"):256}

new_dct = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    new_dct[','.join(k)] = v

print(new_dct)
```

Output:

```
{'name1,name2,name3': 256}
```

Here are a few notes:

- In the code in your question, you use `dicts` without showing what value you assigned to it.
- If (for example) you had initialized `dicts` using `dicts={("name1", 2.0, "name3"):256}`, it would raise the exception you have mentioned (TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found).
- You may want to examine the contents of the dictionary that you iterate over just before the loop to ensure the items in the tuple keys are all of type `str`, otherwise `join()` may not work.

Comment: did you just post their "problematic" code as an answer?

Comment: @Matiss Thanks for your question. I posted working code similar to that of OP but with a clearly initialized input variable `d` in place of the variable `dicts` with unknown value (and also without using the python type name `dict` as a variable name).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same like before in [Convert dictionary key tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092832/convert-dictionary-key-tuple-to-string/73092844#73092844).
Just remove `'s'` in `dicts.items()` as in your first `dict` variable or find another typo in your code espescially in element of `dict` or `dicts`. The exception (TypeError) could be cause by different reference to your `dict` or `dicts` variable. Others' answers already solved it, whether using dict comprehension:

```
dict = {("name1","name2","name3"):256}
new_dct = {','.join(key): value for key, value in dict.items()}
print(new_dct)
```

or normal for loop:

```
dict = {("name1","name2","name3"):256}
new_dct = {}
for key, value in dict.items():
    new_dct[','.join(key)] = value
print(new_dct)
```

and the result will be same output.

```
{'name1,name2,name3': 256}
```